# Android - SupportMapFragment causes part of view to be transparent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I'm developing an app with SupportMapFragment and custom view switching mechanism. Right now i styles app, to make its window to be transparent using styles.xml, but with that change i see a strange problem when using maps. When user switches it current view from one that uses map fragment to another, part of screen that was used by map on previous view becames transparent, for about 1 second.

In image below i present some description, on right i marked using yellow color situation than im talking about:

[image]

on left side is view that i present map using SupportMapFragment, on the right is one i have switched next, with 2 diffrent views(ImageView and TextView),but yellow part of TextView is transparent like my application window, su user can notice eg. apps menu. This is not what im trying to achive so Im looking way to get rid of this effect.

My code for switching views is like follows:

```
public void switchAppView(View view){
  mMainView.removeViewAt(0);
  mMainView.addView(view,0);
}
```

the mMainView is initialized in onCreate Method, by code:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
 super.onCreate(icicle);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 mMainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mymain_layout);
}
```

my activity_main.xml layout presents similar to:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mymain_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/replacable" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
></FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/extra" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to search clues and situations like that but I didnt find any, so if anyone can help i would be grateful, Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> becames transparent, for about 1 second.

I'm guessing you are using black background and you really mean it becomes black.

In that case what you see is a known issue.

You may read more about it here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4659

and here:

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639

Comment: no im not using black background, i have set <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> in my theme for my app, so app window is transparent, my views use diffrent colors background, mostly using layer-lists with few drawables, and even so the part of view remains invisible showing place in system that app was started from eg. part of apps menu.

Comment: @Axxxon I have just checked with `@android:style/Theme.Translucent` and it behaves the same way you describe. You may want to look at these two links to find a workaround for you.

Comment: @Axxxon You may post your own answer with specific info that helped you and accept it instead of mine. This will help other users having the same issue.